# C# SOAP Webservice method returns null

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap

I'm calling a method from a SOAP webservice on a C# project and even though I can see the response arriving with the expected data and format (using fiddler) at the program level the method returns null. Can it be that the function is not properly parsing the response, somehow?

The function is called in standard way (selectedPLCInfo ends up as null)

```
LanDB.DeviceBasicInfo selectedPLCInfo = client.getDeviceBasicInfo(plcHostname);
```

This is the request being sent by the application:

```
POST xxx/soap/soap.fcgi?v=6 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: ""
Host: xxx
Content-Length: 1439
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
    <Auth xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <token xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TIA_Portal_VPG_Manager">token</token>
    </Auth>
</s:Header>
<s:Body s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <q1:getDeviceBasicInfo xmlns:q1="urn:NetworkService"><DeviceName xsi:type="xsd:string">CFP-RE12-VLHCPFM2</DeviceName></q1:getDeviceBasicInfo></s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

And this is the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 10 Jul 2020 10:15:17 GMT
Server: Apache
SOAPServer: SOAP060::Lite/Perl/0.60
Content-Length: 2912
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:types="urn:NetworkDataTypes" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">

<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<namesp3945:getDeviceBasicInfoResponse xmlns:namesp3945="urn:NetworkService">
<DeviceBasicInfo xsi:type="types:DeviceInfo">

(... a ton of expected data here)

</DeviceBasicInfo>
</namesp3945:getDeviceBasicInfoResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: You are getting good results a 200 OK.  So the issue is in the XML Serialization (deserialize).  There is something inconsistent with the c# classes, matching the contract names, and xml data.  Often the issue is with the namespace.  the xml file name root element is Envelope so the contract name should also be Envelope.  You should also have c# classes for Envelope, Body, and DeviceBasicInfo.

Comment: The weird thing is that not all methods have the same issue, only some of them. Anyway, I managed to solve it by adding the Webservice as a Web Reference instead of a Service Reference (everything works fine this way). Go figure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add the service as a Web Reference instead of Service Reference. Further information here:

http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2008/10/interoperability-gotcha-visual-studio.html